# call a function when there's an overflow using numpy.seterr in python

Tags: python, numpy, overflow, raiserror

I'm using

```
np.seterr(under="raise", over ="raise", invalid="raise")
```

at the top of my code.

Then I also have these lines:

```
try:
    weights[i,j] = math.exp(np.clip((beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i]), enthreshold, epthreshold))
except OverflowError:
    print "Calculation failed! weights[i,j] = np.exp(beta + oneminusbeta) = j= " +str(j) + ", i : " + str(i) + " b = " + str(beta[j,i]) + " , omb: " + str(oneminusbeta[j,i])+"\n"
```

But the "Calculation failed!" message that I'm raising doesn't come up. I only get the overflow error:

```
FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

How can I capture the overflow error so that I handle it in a certain way without my program crashing? I'd be happy to catch and deal with the overflow without using `numpy.seterr()`, if that's possible.

Comment: Apparently Numpy doesn't raise `builtins.OverflowError` but `builtins.FloatingPointError`

Comment: does that mean that on the third line of the code snippet, I should be using `except FloatingPointError` instead of `except OverflowError`?

Comment: Exactly, then at least you will catch that error. But since division by zero, overflow, underflow, and encountering an invalid value all raise `FloatingPointError`, you could be more specific by using the [`seterrcall`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterrcall.html) functionality.